# Why can't I get this concatenation to work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have worked with Windows Form applications but am very new to web development. I am having a problem figuring out how to concatenate 2 text boxes to fill in the text for the 3rd box.  I am entering the first name in txtFirstName and the last name in txtLastName1.  I would like to have txtFullName populated with the first and last names combined.

The code is placed in an ASP content placeholder.

this is the ASP code I am currently testing without getting any results.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Width="175px" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLname1" runat="server" Width="175px" TabIndex="3"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" Width="268px" Text='<%#Eval("cpMainContent_txtFname") + " "+  Eval("cpMainContent_txtLname1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

However nothing happens when I enter data in the first name and last name text boxes when the web page is rendered.  I know I am missing something to cause the concatenation to happen. any help would be appreciated.

I have also attempted this via this java script

```
<script language="javascript">
function AppendValues(form)
{
   var TextBox1 = form.txtFirstName.value;
   var TextBox2 = form.txtLname1.value;
   form.txtFullName.value = Textbox1 + TextBox2;
   }
   </script>
  <INPUT type = text name="textbox1" onChange="AppendValues(this.form);">
  <INPUT type = text name="textbox2" onChange="AppendValues(this.form);">
  <INPUT type = text name="textbox3" READONLY>
```

Visual studios 2013 complained about using the language= in the first line of the java script and the code would not compile.

Comment: are you see something about this construction: `<%#Eval` ? do you know how use it?

Comment: **note**: _onchange_ raise only after lost focus, befor blur event

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have [ClientIDMode="Static"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Change

```
   var TextBox1 = form.txtFirstName.value;
   var TextBox2 = form.txtLname1.value;
   form.txtFullName.value = Textbox1 + TextBox2;
```

to

```
   var TextBox1 =document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value;
   var TextBox2 = document.getElementById('txtLname1').value;
   document.getElementById('txtFullName').value = Textbox1 + TextBox2;
```

Otherwise, do

```
   var TextBox1 =document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').value;
   var TextBox2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtLname1.ClientID %>').value;
   document.getElementById('<%= txtFullName.ClientID %>').value = Textbox1 + TextBox2;
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('txtFirstName')` this would work only if server textbox have [`ClientIDMode="Static"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: you can add code for case when this attribute not set, like `document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>')` also

Comment: @Grundy, will that code work whether or not ClientMode=Static ?

Comment: this `document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>')` work always, since return id from server control, this `document.getElementById('txtFirstName')` work only when _ClientIDMode_ set to _"Static"_ or when server control not it naming container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78225/discussion-between-grundy-and-ammarcse).